# Running Windows service built against .net framework 1.0 in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a .net Windows service built using .net framework 1.0 and using all .net 1.0 assembly references. Now I would like to run that service on a Windows Server 2012 R2, but it does not support .net 1.0. Is there any way to run this service on Windows Server 2012 R2?

I tried to redirect assemblies to .net 2.0 assemblies using assembly redirect in app.config but I'm still receiving error 1053 while starting services and this could be because loading incorrect assemblies. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Since Windows Server 2012 R2 does **not** support .NET Framework 1.0 - no, there is no way to run this service on this server. You'll need to re-compile this service against a more recent version of the .NET framework

Comment: ok.. recompiling against latest version is one option but can we achieve this by redirecting to 2.0 assemblies from application configuration file..

Comment: No, you cannot. What you can do with assembly redirection is specifying a specific version for an assembly - e.g. redirect all requests for "Json.NET" to version 7.0 of that assembly. You **CANNOT** however magically redirect to a new version of the .NET Framework using this technique.

Comment: I'm only trying to redirect referenced dlls used in that service to latest version. e.g. My service using system.dll of version 1.0.5000.0 and now i'm trying to redirect it to version 2.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will not work, which has been stated previously in the comments.
Your only two options are:

1. Recompile the application against a newer supported framework and deal with any remediation that comes from that (broken contracts, deprecated functionality, etc.)
2. Run the service on an older version of Server that supports .Net 1.0

Since you stated that recompiling the code is an option, in my opinion that is by far your best option for many reasons, not the least of which being able to use a supported framework on a supported OS.